# maven pass arguments to pom java.library.path cplex

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to resolve this error that I keep getting:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no cplex1262 in java.library.path
java.library.path must point to the directory containing the CPLEX shared library
try invoking java with java -Djava.library.path=...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX([I)J
at ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX(Native Method)
at ilog.cplex.CplexI.init(CplexI.java:5722)
at ilog.cplex.CplexI.(CplexI.java:611)
at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.(IloCplex.java:10384)
```

I am using maven with java and I am trying to call cplex library. I think something needs to change in the pom file but i dont know what. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for could be your dll being in 32 or 64 bits and your java being in the opposite architecture.
Try verifying that your java and cplex.dll match.  I got this information from the below post [UnsatisfiedLinkError, despite setting Djava.library.path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482281/unsatisfiedlinkerror-despite-setting-djava-library-path-variable)