# UnsatisfiedLinkError for tomcat7 windowsOS

Tags: java, tomcat7, jna, java-security

I am getting below error on my web app.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain updateLastError method for class com.sun.jna.Native
com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:139)
com.sun.jna.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:41)
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLEByReference.<init>(WinNT.java:1114)
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLEByReference.<init>(WinNT.java:1110)
waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.logonDomainUserEx(WindowsAuthProviderImpl.java:193)
waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.logonDomainUser(WindowsAuthProviderImpl.java:181)
waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.logonUser(WindowsAuthProviderImpl.java:212)
waffle.apache.MixedAuthenticator.post(MixedAuthenticator.java:233)
waffle.apache.MixedAuthenticator.authenticate(MixedAuthenticator.java:112)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:577)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
```

I searched that it may be due to some old version access of jna but removing jna is giving me NoClassDefErrors for com.sun.jna.Pointer. Also tried -Djna.nosys=true but its also not solving the issue.

I also tried -Djava.library.path=
from [What is the cause of an UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446426/what-is-the-cause-of-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror) but it is also not working..

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You've got a version mismatch somewhere; your Java and native parts of JNA aren't matching up.  Set -Djna.debug_load.jna to see where the native bits are being loaded from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by deleting an old jnidispatch.dll file from my machine.
I'm using Gradle and Tomcat on Windows 7.
Delete the `jnidispatch.dll` file in `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\native\jna\win32-amd64`

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to just comment, but this is vaguely similar to a question i asked a couple years ago called [UnsatisfiedLinkError, despite setting Djava.library.path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482281/unsatisfiedlinkerror-despite-setting-djava-library-path-variable)
Somebody suggested making sure i was using the right architecture type, i.e. using 64 bit jdk with 64 bit Tomcat & 32 with 32.  Does that match up?

Comment: This project was running fine few days back. Also there was no change in installation of java or tomcat. It suddenly started giving this error after server restart...So I guess there might be some configuration issue during start of tomcat..